# Model theory textbook to learn about the consistency and independency proofs

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic, model-theory, education, forcing

Is there a model theory textbook that describes how to build boolean-valued models to prove the consistency of a sentence with a theory? It would be great if the book also contained basic techniques to prove the independence of a sentence from a given set of sentences. P.S. I'm a beginner and looking for a rather clear and not encyclopedic book. I already have Keisler's, Tent's and Hodges' electronic books but don't know if they are good to study the topics I've mentioned.

Comment: What I can say is that model theory would be not what you are looking for. (There may be textbooks on Boolean-valued models for general first-order theories, but I am not sure they are studied for establishing independence results.) Try textbooks for set theory, reverse mathematics, models of *arithmetic*, or proof theory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not find Boolean-valued models in any model theory textbooks. Instead, you want a set theory book that takes the Boolean-values models approach to forcing.

The classic is Bell's *Set Theory: Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs*.

Another option is Jech's *Set Theory*, but this book is definitely encyclopedic!

Comment: thanks for your recommendations! I actually didn't know if there was such a book. Also, I was a bit more interested in the corresponding techniques applied to general first-order theories, not necessarily ZFC. P.S. Trying to find some illegal preview of the Bell's book :)

Comment: I'm not aware of any applications of Boolean valued models to general first-order theories - certainly not anything established enough to appear in textbooks. Perhaps the closest thing is work on sheaves of models or model theory in toposes. You might be interested in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472587/boolean-valued-models-why-should-i-care), which seems very similar to yours.